How to solve Error: EPERM: operation not permitted in Visual Studio Code with Sveltekit?
Lately I'm getting the "EPERM: operation not permitted" error in Visual Studio Code while working on my SvelteKit project. It also happens on new projects. The error occurs randomly (when using npm commands, deleting folders, moving folders etc.). I'm working on a clean installed Windows 11 laptop and had no issues with my previous laptop (same projects/same directories etc.)
A list of random errors:

[
npm WARN cleanup     'C:\Webdev\svelte-app-capacitor2\node_modules\.p-limit-b0Htm7uU',
npm WARN cleanup     [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rmdir 'C:\Webdev\svelte-app-capacitor2\node_modules.p-limit-b0Htm7uU'] {
npm WARN cleanup       errno: -4048,
npm WARN cleanup       code: 'EPERM',
npm WARN cleanup       syscall: 'rmdir',
npm WARN cleanup       path: 'C:\Webdev\svelte-app-capacitor2\node_modules\.p-limit-b0Htm7uU'
npm WARN cleanup     }
npm WARN cleanup   ],

PS C:\Webdev\svelte-app-capacitor2> npm run dev -- --host

> svelte-app@0.0.1 dev
> vite dev --host

Forced re-optimization of dependencies
error when starting dev server:
Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rmdir 'C:\Webdev\svelte-app-capacitor2\node_modules\.vite\deps'

× copy android - failed!
[error] Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rmdir
        'C:\Webdev\svelte-app-capacitor2\android\app\src\main\assets\public\audio'

I did a lot of research and did the following (without results):

Granted the right permissions on the folder(s) (full controll)
Run Visual Studio Code as admin.
Check for Node.js Version Issues
Using CMD instead of Visual Studio Code
Delete node_modules and npm install the project again (this works the best, but for short times)
Adjusted my Antivirus and granted permissions for the folders.
Enabled Long Path Support.
Checked Disk(chkdsk /f)


Could you fix this issue? I'm having a similar problem right now.
